# Image Reposition and cropping feature in flutter

Tags: flutter, image

[image]

Hello, Can any body please give me suggestion how to do this feature in flutter. User will select and image from gallery and can do cropping, and reposition. Attached image can provide better idea of this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I think you can achieve doing this by a package try to check this out crop_your_image as the named of the package

Answer (score 0):

There are so many plugins and packages for that but there's one package called   `image_cropper` ([link](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper)) which supports android, iOS, and the web.

Also, they have preset for limiting the cropping to square only or the same aspect ratio. So that you can **enable,disable** features according to your needs.